# reseting the canvas bitmap doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, memory, user-interface, canvas, bitmap

i try to paint an arrow png on canvas with a png bitmap behind it. so every time i rotate the arrow i have to reset the background bitmap of the canvas becouse otherwise i would see duplicates of the old arrows.

i reset the background with:

```
bMapLoad.eraseColor(0);
```

the problem is that sometimes it erases parts of the new arrow. sow that i sometimes only see a part of the arrow. i rotate it aber every 10-100 ms.

can someone help me?

i also tried:

```
bMapLoad=bMapcanvasBack.copy(bMapcanvasBack.getConfig(), true);
canvasLoad.setBitmap(bMapLoad);
```

this works fine but needs more memory. so is there a better way?

edit:

also

```
canvasLoad.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
```

don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `canvas.drawARGB(0,0,0,0)` or, more concise `canvas.drawColor(0)` to clear it, then draw the bitmap again (`canvas.drawBitmap(...)`)

The partial overdrawing may have a different reason though - synchronization between drawing and display. A common practice is to use double buffering. This means, you would draw on a offscreen canvas, and then exchange the underlying Bitmap with the visible canvas.

EDIT: some useful resources on double buffering with android:

An [example here](http://android-coding.blogspot.de/2012/01/flickering-problems-due-to-double.html) plus the book "beginning android games" also features a section on double buffering. The source code for the book can be downloaded [here](http://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games/source/checkout)

Comment: @5w4rley maybe I am wrong about the first 0 of ARGB - please try canvas.drawColor(0). If this doesn't work, then probably you're trying to clear the wrong canvas - the `drawX`calls do work.

Comment: i allready tryed canvasLoad.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); but with the same resultate as bMapLoad.eraseColor(0);

Comment: @5w4rley clearing works then, IIUYC. you seem to need double buffering. OR, try to invalidate the view before clearing (with `invalidate()`)

Comment: hmm well doesn't really work. think i'll have to stay at bMapLoad=bMapcanvasBack.copy(bMapcanvasBack.getConfig(), true);
canvasLoad.setBitmap(bMapLoad);

Comment: @5w4rley - godspeed :) but if you decide to try double buffering - it isnt that compicated after all - I edited the answer to include some resources